# ¿Se puede exportar un procedimiento almacenado de una base de datos a otra? (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, transact-sql

básicamente lo que necesito es replicar los procedimientos de una base de datos a otra (por ejemplo copiar los sp de una base de datos de prueba a una de productivo), estuve viendo como extraer el código mediante el `SP_HELPTEXT` y `SYS.SYSOBJECTS` pero no se como pasarlo a la base de datos destino

Answer (score 2):

Si dispones de SQL Server Management Studio, lo puedes realizar con la herramienta de exportación de scripts.

**Paso 1:**
Desde el explorador de objetos, botón derecho sobre la base de datos de origen.

[image: Generar Scripts]

Ventana de introducción = siguiente.

**Paso 2:**
Marcar en Stored Procedures y Next.

[image: Escoger objetos]

**Paso 3:**

Es indiferente si lo guardas en un archivo, o en una nueva ventana, pero aquí nos iremos a Advanced, ya que estableceremos algún pequeño cambio en lo que viene configurado por defecto.

[image: Paso 3]

**Paso 4:**
Dependiendo del Sql que dispongas, las opciones pueden tener algunas variaciones. Revísalas todas para adecuarlas a lo que necesitas, pero es especialmente interesante poner:

**Script USE DATABASE en False**

[image: Paso 4]

Cuando este configurado **Ok**

**Next**

Ventana de revisión: **Next**

Ahora solo te queda aplicar el mismo a la base de datos destino.